# Symfony Cache InvalidArgumantException

Tags: php, symfony, caching

I need help with understanding symfony cache component. I have inherited script from other programmer with symfony form for create an item. This:

```
class OfferController extends Controller
{
    public function createAction(Request $request) {
        $api_offer = $this->get('gamexp_affiliates.api.admin.offer');
        $api_user = $this->get('gamexp_affiliates.api.admin.user');
        $api_project = $this->get('gamexp_affiliates.api.admin.project');
        $api_goal = $this->get('gamexp_affiliates.api.admin.goal');
        $tpl = '@GamexpAffiliates/Admin/Offer/Form/create.html.twig';

        $offer_webmasters = $offer_projects = $offer_goals = null;

        $sendCommonResponse = function(FormInterface $form = null, $code = 200, $headers = []) use ($tpl, &$offer_webmasters, &$offer_projects, &$offer_goals) {
            $params = [
                'offer_webmasters' => $offer_webmasters,
                'offer_projects' => $offer_projects,
                'offer_goals' => $offer_goals,
            ];
            $response = $this->render($tpl, $form ? array_merge([
                'offer' => $form->createView(),
            ], $params) : $params, new Response('', $code, $headers));
            return $response;
        };

        $selectProject = function($project_id) use ($api_project, &$offer_projects, &$projects_sort, &$projects_count) {
            $project = null;
            if ($project_id > 0 && is_numeric($project_id)) {
                foreach ($offer_projects as $offer_project) {
                    if ($project_id == $offer_project['id']) {
                        $project = $offer_project;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!$project) {

                    try {
                        if ($project = $api_project->findProjectByIdWithLandings($project_id, ['id', 'name', 'status'])) {
                            if ($projects_count <= $cnt = count($offer_projects)) {
                                $offer_projects = array_slice($offer_projects, $cnt - $projects_count + 1, $projects_count);
                            }
                            $offer_projects = array_merge($offer_projects, [$project]);
                            if ($projects_sort) {
                                usort($offer_projects, function(array $a, array $b) use ($api_project, $projects_sort) {
                                    foreach ($projects_sort as $field => $sort_type) {

                                        if ($comp = $sort_type === $api_project::SORT_ASCENDING ? strnatcmp($a[$field], $b[$field]) : strnatcmp($b[$field], $a[$field])) {
                                            return $comp;
                                        }
                                        continue;
                                    }
                                    return 0;
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (\Exception $e) {
                        $this->get('logger')->error("Ошибка: " . $e->getMessage() . "на строке: " . $e->getLine());
                    }
                }
            }
            return $project;
        };

        $createForm = function($data, $project = null, $landings = null) use ($api_offer, &$offer_webmasters, &$offer_projects, &$offer_goals) {
            $params = [
                'action' => $this->generateUrl('gamexp_affiliates.admin.api.offer.create'),
                'statuses' => $api_offer->getAvailableStatuses($landings ? array_unique(array_column($landings, 'status')) : null),
                'offer_webmasters' => $offer_webmasters,
                'offer_projects' => $offer_projects,
                'offer_goals' => $offer_goals,
            ];
            if ($project && !empty($project['landings'])) {
                $params['offer_landings'] = $project['landings'];
            }

            return $this->createForm(AdminOfferCreateType::class, $data, $params);
        };

        try {
            if (!$offer_webmasters = $api_user->findAll(null, 10, 0, ['id', 'email', 'phone'])) {
                return $sendCommonResponse();
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $sendCommonResponse();
        }

        try {
            if (!$offer_projects = $api_project->findAllProjectsWithLandingsAndUser(null, 10, 0, ['id', 'name', 'status'])) {
                return $sendCommonResponse();
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $sendCommonResponse();
        }

        try {
            if (!$offer_goals = $api_goal->findAllItems(null, 10, 0, ['id', 'name', 'revshare', 'status'])) {
                return $sendCommonResponse();
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $sendCommonResponse();
        }

        $fast_mode = false;
        if ($request->isMethod('GET')) {

            $fast_mode = (0 < $project_id = $request->get('project') and is_numeric($project_id)); 
        } else {
            $project_id = null;
        }

        if ($project = $selectProject($project_id)) {
            $data = [
                'project' => $project['id'],
            ];
        } else {
            $data = null;
        }

        $form = $createForm($data, $project);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
            if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException();
            }

            if (!$request->isMethod('POST')) {
                throw $this->createHttpException(405);
            }

            $data = $form->getData();


            $landings = [];
            if ($project = $selectProject(isset($data['project']) ? $data['project'] : null)) {
                if (!empty($data['landings']) && !empty($project['landings'])) {
                    $data['landings'] = array_intersect($data['landings'], array_column($project['landings'], 'id'));

                    foreach ($project['landings'] as $landing) {
                        if (in_array($landing['id'], $data['landings'])) {
                            $landings[$landing['id']] = $landing;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            $form = $createForm($data, $project, $landings);
            $form->handleRequest($request);
            $data = $form->getData();

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                if ($res = $this->linkApiResponseToForm($form, function(FormInterface $form, array $params) use ($api_offer, $data, $sendCommonResponse) {
                    if (in_array('project_selection', $params['validation_groups']) || in_array('landings_selection', $params['validation_groups']) || in_array('header_image_upload', $params['validation_groups'])) {
                        if (in_array('header_image_upload', $params['validation_groups'])) {
                            if (isset($data['header_image']) && $data['header_image'] instanceof UploadedFile) {
                                $api_offer->saveHeaderImage($data['header_image']);
                            }
                        }
                        return $sendCommonResponse($form, 300, [
                            'Location' => $this->generateUrl('gamexp_affiliates.admin.api.offer.create'),
                        ]);
                    }
                    $data['creator'] = $this->getUser()->getId();
                    if ($id = (int)$api_offer->createOffer($data)) {
                        return new JsonResponse([
                            'id' => $id,
                            'name' => trim($data['name']),
                        ], 201, [
                            'Location' => $this->generateUrl('gamexp_affiliates.admin.api.offer.update', ['id' => $id]),
                        ]);
                    }
                })) {
                    return $res;
                }
            }
            return $sendCommonResponse($form, 400);
        } elseif ($fast_mode && !$data['project']) {
            $this->addFlash($form->getName().':warning', 'Проекта, который вы выбрали, не существует. Возможно кто-то другой его только что удалил. Попробуйте выбрать другой проект из списка.');
        }

        return $sendCommonResponse($form);
    }
}
```

I have this exception:

> request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\Cache\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: "Cache key
>   length must be greater than zero" at
>   /home/ruslan/Projects/partners_prod/cache/prod/classes.php line 1747
>   {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Cache\Exception\InvalidArgumentException(code:
>   0): Cache key length must be greater than zero at
>   /home/ruslan/Projects/partners_prod/cache/prod/classes.php:1747)"} []

And it's only happened when I am on prod environment. In dev all work fine! Initialy the page loads fine, but then I get ajax request for some extra data exception happens. When I went along the code with debuger It fails at $form->isSubmited() point. After $form->handelRequest() method. What the meaninig of this exception? I hadn't added to cache any keys! How it works? I strongly need to know the base issue of this exception. Help me please to understend it. Great thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Finally I have found the solution after two days. Maybe it'll help someone in future. The problem was in form. Exactly in constraints. It was like form submit, but the form was not valid at all. For every field symfony have a key somehow in cache but it is not a cache value. And if field is required but not present it triggered an Exception. Because in this case the key is empty string. After I had chosen all nesessary fields it have worked fine.